Using Rankine-Hugoniot jump conditions to solve a Riemann problem for a linear, hyperbolic system of PDEs
Given a linear, hyperbolic system of PDEs,
$$ \partial_t\mathbf{q} + \mathbf{A} \partial_x\mathbf{q} = 0,$$
I understand that we can solve a Riemann problem for this system using a method involving the right eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$, for example, as given in Riemann Problem for Linear Hyperbolic Systems.
However, I was wondering if I can use the Rankine-Hugoniot jump conditions instead to solve the Riemann problem. I can rewrite the system of equations as
$$ \partial_t\mathbf{q} + \partial_x\mathbf{f} = 0 $$
where $\mathbf{f} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{q}$ since $\mathbf{A}$ is constant. Further, assuming I know the wave-speeds of the system, is it possible to use the Rankine-Hugoniot jump conditions to find the star states of the system? As an example, let us consider a linear system of three equations with the system having wave speeds $\lambda_0$, $\lambda_1$, and $\lambda_2$. Further, let us call the initial states $\mathbf{q}_L$ and $\mathbf{q}_R$, and the two intermediate states $\mathbf{q}_L^*$ and $\mathbf{q}_R^*$. There are three jump equations (of course each equation is actually a system of three equations)
\begin{align}
\mathbf{f}_L^* - \mathbf{f}_L &= \lambda_0 (\mathbf{q}_L^* - \mathbf{q}_L) \\
\mathbf{f}_R^* - \mathbf{f}_L^* &= \lambda_1 (\mathbf{q}_R^* - \mathbf{q}_L^*) \\
\mathbf{f}_R - \mathbf{f}_R^* &= \lambda_2 (\mathbf{q}_R - \mathbf{q}_R^*). \\
\end{align}
Since I'm only concerned with finding the solution to the Riemann problem and not the flux, would it suffice to solve two of these equations, say the first and the third to find the intermediate states? If not, where is the flaw in the logic/reasoning?
